# R Markdown. Pdf Output of a table from .csv. Problem with creating a line with columns totals

Tags: r, sum, r-markdown, row

This is my first week with R.

I'm trying to create monthly timesheets for different staff members from a single specific .csv file, including all the days and tasks for the period of the whole project.

The file is [here](https://github.com/InflatableGull/data_initiative_timesheets/blob/master/ts_lastname_firstname_ver2.Rmd):

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: default
classoption: landscape
geometry: "left=1cm,right=1cm,top=0.6cm,bottom=0.6cm"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, comment=NA)
```

```{r}
# A Prefix nulling hook.

# Make sure to keep the default for normal processing.
default_output_hook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("output")

# Output hooks handle normal R console output.
knitr::knit_hooks$set( output = function(x, options) {

  comment <- knitr::opts_current$get("comment")
  if( is.na(comment) ) comment <- ""
  can_null <- grepl( paste0( comment, "\\s*\\[\\d?\\]" ),
                     x, perl = TRUE)
  do_null <- isTRUE( knitr::opts_current$get("null_prefix") )
  if( can_null && do_null ) {
    # By default R print output aligns at the right brace.
    align_index <- regexpr( "\\]", x )[1] - 1
    # Two cases: start or newline
    re <- paste0( "^.{", align_index, "}\\]")
    rep <- comment
    x <- gsub( re, rep,  x )
    re <- paste0( "\\\n.{", align_index, "}\\]")
    rep <- paste0( "\n", comment )
    x <- gsub( re, rep,  x )
  }

  default_output_hook( x, options )

})

knitr::opts_template$set("kill_prefix"=list(comment=NA, null_prefix=TRUE))
```

```{r General Parameters, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

# read the source file
data_source <- read.csv("ts_lastname_firstname.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

# Conversion to Date format from text in source file first column
data_source[,1] <- as.Date(data_source[,1], (format="%Y-%m-%d"))

# for verifying class of the Data Frame: 
#class(data_source[, 1])
```

```{r Output for 2019 10}
# Division of the Tasks (too many columns for one page) and Subsets for 2019
partA201910 <- subset(data_source, data_source[,1] >= "2019-10-01" & data_source[,1] <= "2019-10-31", 1:23)
partB201910 <- subset(data_source, data_source$Day >= "2019-10-01" & data_source$Day <= "2019-10-31", c(1, 24:46))

# Sum of the Columns
SourceTableColsSumA <- colSums(partA201910[-1])
SourceTableColsSumB <- colSums(partB201910[-1])

x <- bind_rows(partA201910,SourceTableColsSumA)
#rbind(partA201910, SourceTableColsSum)
y <- bind_rows(partB201910,SourceTableColsSumB)
#rbind(partA201910, SourceTableColsSum)
```

# **TIMESHEET - project Name** 
**Company:** Acme inc. **Member of Staff:** FirstName LastName **Employed:** full-time 
**Year:** 2020 **Month:** March **Page 1/2**
```{r}
kable(x, "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options= c("scale_down","striped"))
```
\newpage
# **TIMESHEET - project Name** 
**Company:** Acme inc. **Member of Staff:** FirstName LastName **Employed:** full-time 
**Year:** 2020 **Month:** March **Page 2/2**
```{r}
kable(y, "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options= c("scale_down","striped"))
```
**Date and signature | Employee** _________________________\
\
\
**Date and signature | Project Manager - Supervisor**_________________________
````

The source file for raw data is [here](https://github.com/InflatableGull/data_initiative_timesheets/blob/master/ts_lastname_firstname.csv) (a .csv file).

The output file is [here](https://github.com/InflatableGull/data_initiative_timesheets/blob/master/ts_lastname_firstname_ver2.pdf).

I'm having some results, but I'm stuck with the output as I need:

1. a line at the end of each of the two tables with columns totals
2. a column at the end of each of the two tables with the sums of each row.

For now, let's stick with 1. Actually, I have the row with totals, but the file produces NA in the first cell. I'm trying with

```
x <- bind_rows(partA201910,c("Total", SourceTableColsSumA))
```

in line 72 but while in other situations it works, here I have an error message "Column 'T2.1' can't be converted from integer to charachter"

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (assuming columns `1:5` to summarize):

```
library(dplyr)

# Add column at the end with sums of every row
your_data_set %>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
   mutate(row_sum=rowSums(.[1:5]))

# Create row (data frame) that gives sums of every column
your_data_set %>%
   replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(sum)) -> column_totals

# Combine to the final data set
final_data_set <- bind_rows(your_data_set, column_totals)

# Clean working directory
rm(list = c("your_data_set", "column_totals"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the feedback. I have updated the file here 

https://github.com/InflatableGull/data_initiative_timesheets/blob/master/ts_lastname_firstname_v2.Rmd

and the .pdf here (see only page 1)
https://github.com/InflatableGull/data_initiative_timesheets/blob/master/ts_lastname_firstname_v2.pdf

one step at the time. More or less I managed to have a column with totals, as following your code I get the error 

Error in Summary.Date(c(18170, 18171, 18172, 18173, 18174, 18175, 18176, : sum not defined for "Date" objects...

Comment: Well, this happens because you probably try to `sum` over `date`. You need to skip this column, e.g., like this `your_data_set %>% summarise_at(vars(-date), funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) -> your_data_set`

Hope this helps!